# Easy way to initilize a container class member before C++11?

Tags: c++

First see link: http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html

I'm trying to rewrite the C++11 code for A* to an older C++ standard, how would you write the initialization of the graph in an elegant way with minimal copies?

**EDIT:**
If you don't like non standard hash_map from below example just ignore that and substitute it with a std::map.

```
#include <queue>
#include <hash_map>

using namespace std;

template<typename Loc>
struct Graph {
  typedef Loc Location;
  typedef typename vector<Location>::iterator iterator;
  std::hash_map<Location, vector<Location> > edges;

  inline const vector<Location> neighbors(Location id) {
    return edges[id];
  }
};

int main()
{
   // C++11 syntax that needs to be rewritten
   Graph<char> example_graph = {{
     {'A', {'B'}},
     {'B', {'A', 'C', 'D'}},
     {'C', {'A'}},
     {'D', {'E', 'A'}},
     {'E', {'B'}}
   }};

  return 0;
}
```

I would like to have something like:

```
Graph<char> example_graph;
...
example_graph.addEdge(edge, edge_neighbors_vector) // Pass a vector to initialize the other vector, that means copying from one vector to the other... is there a better way?
// OR
example_graph.addEdge(pair) // pair of edge and neighbors?
```

Maybe variable argument list?

Comment: That depends on what `std::hash_map` is? AFAIK, both in C++03 and C++11, there's no such container. There's `std::unordered_map`, did you mean to use that? If yes, the question may be moot since you'd be using a C++11 container with no C++11 supporting compiler? Hmm...

Comment: @legends2k, most compilers provided a container called `hash_map` long, long before `unordered_map` (that's why the unordered containers have such ungainly names, rather than the more obvious `hash_map`!) So `std::hash_map` is obviously one of those non-standard extensions.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: Thanks for clarifying that hash_map is a non-standard extension, and to add to the confusion originally hash_map was added to namespace std (It was later moved to stdext namespace)

Comment: @CrHasher, that depends on your compiler, because `stdext` is non-standard too. GCC's hash_map is in namespace `__gnu_cxx`

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: Ok, thank you for the extra info

Comment: Lets say that hash_map is just an arbitrary container in this example I could have used a simple map instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a helper structure to capture the node information in the graph. It acts like a pair, but lets you associate arbitrary neighbors.

```
template<typename Loc>
struct Node : pair<Loc, vector<Loc> > {
  Node (Loc l) { pair<Loc, vector<Loc> >::first = l; }
  Node & operator << (Loc n) {
    pair<Loc, vector<Loc> >::second.push_back(n);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Then, assuming you have defined a constructor for your graph that will pass the iterators to the underlying map, you can do something like this to define an array of nodes:

```
Node<char> graph_init[] = {
   Node<char>('A') << 'B',
   Node<char>('B') << 'A' << 'C' << 'D',
   Node<char>('C') << 'A',
   Node<char>('D') << 'E' << 'A',
   Node<char>('E') << 'B',
};

Graph<char> example_graph(graph_init, graph_init + 5);
```

Feel free to use your favorite array member counting technique rather than a magic value.